# Provider "MediaProvider" is in use

Tags: android, process, media, android-contentprovider, android-music-player

My current task involves fixing an Android music player that *sucks too much RAM*. By taking a look at the "Apps" section of the system settings, I found a mysterious (for me) process called `Media`. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Media process]

I would like to know more about this process and about the reason why it appears *every time a song is played* and disappears *every time the playback stops*. The only reference I have been able to find in the official documentation is [this one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html).

What does the `MediaProvider` class do? 
Do you have any clue about what may be causing that process to be kept alive during the playback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself. Turned out that a `Cursor` was being left open (I don't know whether accidentally or willfully), thus causing the `Media` process to appear.

Still, it is weird that, neither in the official SDK documentation nor on the Net, there is no mention about any `MediaProvider`-ish thing.